# Instantiate an object of one class in the constructor of another class C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, constructor

I'm writting a basic game in C++ which features 3 classes: `Game` class, `Character` class and `Item` class.

The `Game` class will have all the logic of the game, so that the `main` function will just simply create the `Game object`, call its logic function and the game will do everything else. There can be more than 1 player.

The `Character` class has a vector of pointers that can hold one or more Items. A character can have one or more items

The `Item` class has all the attributes and functionality of the item.

I'm stuck at designing the structure of the game. Someone suggested me to structure my game in a way that when the `Game object` is created, it also creates an `Character object`, and that Character object will then create a vector of pointers to hold Item, and the `Item object`. So it likes when I call the `constructor of the Game class`, it will call the `constructor of the Character class`, and the constructor of the Character class will automatically call the `constructor of the Item class`.

It makes sense, but I couldn't figure out how to properly implement it.

This is what I've got
This is what I have so far:

Game.cpp

```
Game::Game()
{
        vector<Character*> characterVector; //to hold Characters
}

Game::startLogic()
{
    string name;
    Character character = new Character(name);
}
```

Character.cpp

```
Character::Character(string name)
{
    m_name = name;
    vector<Item*> itemVector;
}
```

Item.cpp

```
Item::Item()
{ //initialise all the attributes of an item 
}
```

main.cpp

```
void main()
{
    Game g;
    g.startLogic();
}
```

So I could create a character when the game runs (I still have to push that character into the characterVector later though), but I'm not quite sure on how to create items for that character. I means where should I put that instantiate code? In the startLogic function, in the constructor of Game, or in the constructor of Character?

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Probably most of your logic will go into your [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) `Game`.

Comment: oh the reason for a vector of pointers is cuz basically, this game is actually about interacting with items (combine, match). the character is just like an avatar of the player. it's just for the sake that the game is coded in a way that it can be expanded later to have more than one character (player)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vectors are in the wrong places.  You need to move them into the class declarations as class members, not as local variables inside the constructors.  The constructors can **fill** the vectors (but really, do characters know what items they are "born" with, and do games know what characters are alive as soon as the game start?), but should not **declare** them.

Try this instead:

Game.h

```
#include <vector>

class Character;

class Game
{
public:
    std::vector<Character*> characters;

    Game();
    ~Game();
    void startLogic();
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Character.h"
#include <memory>

Game::Game()
{
}

Game::~Game()
{
    for (std::vector<Character*>::iterator i = characters.begin();
        i != characters.end();
        ++i)
    {
        delete *i;
    }
}

Game::startLogic()
{
    ...

    // using auto_ptr as a safety catch in case of memory errors...

    std::auto_ptr<Character> c(new Character("Joe Smoe"));

    std::auto_ptr<Item> i(new Item);
    c->items.push_back(i.get());
    i.release();

    characters.push_back(c.get());
    c.release();

    ...
}
```

Character.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Item;

class Character
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Item*> items;

    Character(std::string aName);
    ~Character();
};
```

Character.cpp

```
#include "Character.h"
#include "Item.h"

Character::Character(std::string aName)
    : name(aName)
{
}

Character::~Character()
{
    for (std::vector<Item*>::iterator i = items.begin();
        i != items.end();
        ++i)
    {
        delete *i;
    }
}
```

Item.h

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item();
};
```

Item.cpp

```
#include "Item.h"

Item::Item()
{ //initialise all the attributes of an item 
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Game g;
    g.startLogic();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your awesome answer, i didn't expect to receive a detailed answer like this. I wonder if I have to declare those vectors as public? and the mechanism of the game is when the player starts, they will have a chance to create a character with the name of his choice, then add items to the character's inventory

Comment: No, the vectors do not need to be public. Simply add additional methods to the `Character` class to add/remove/access the items as needed.